# How I can lock a folder from deletion in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, permissions, file-permissions

I am running Windows 8, and I have a personal folder that I want to prevent from being deleted/moved/cut. I looked into Windows folder security options ("Read & Execute", "Read" and "Write"), but that doesn't seem to work. How do I lock the folder from being deleted?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I lock a folder so that it CANNOT be erased?](http://superuser.com/questions/271712/how-can-i-lock-a-folder-so-that-it-cannot-be-erased)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 It isn't a duplicate. The linked post only applies to Windows XP. The settings menu is quite different in Windows 8 and 10 (I'm assuming Windows 8 is similar to Windows 10, since the answer below worked for me).

Answer (score 1):

An administrator will always be able to take ownership and delete the folder if they have a clue.

1. Right Click > Properties > SECURITY tab > ADVANCED button
2. Click Disable Inheritance
3. Click "Convert inherited permissions..."
4. Select the "USERS (*COMPUTERNAME*\USERS)" group and click edit
5. Click "Show advanced permissions"
6. Now you are able to remove the two delete permissions.

You can also remove this permission for other groups but as I said, an admin will always be able to change the permissions back.

Comment: It works. In my case, I only wanted the folders and its subfolders to be protected, so I unchecked the delete option only, and applied it to the folders and subfolders only.